# Option Button User for m to chnage Column Font Colour

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have two Option Buttons in a user form and I need to do the following.

If Option Button 1 is clicked, then make the ENTIRE column F in white font (the text only)

If Option Button 2 is clicked, then make the ENTIRE column F in dark blue font (the text only).

I've come up with the code below, but the problem is that when I click any of the Option Buttons, the macro changes the font color of my whole worksheet and I want to change it ONLY in COLUMN F.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click() 
'Option Button Hide 
Columns("F:F").Select 
Range("F114").Activate 
With Selection.Font 
.Color = -10477568 
.TintAndShade = 0 
End With
End Sub 

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click() 
'Option Button Unhide 
Columns("F:F").Select 
Range("F114").Activate
With Selection.Font 
.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1 
.TintAndShade = 0 
End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your post and include your code in it (not as comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the `Select` and `Selection` to get this that will work properly :

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    'Option Button Hide
    With Columns("F:F").Font
        .Color = -10477568
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    'Option Button Unhide
    With Columns("F:F").Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

standing your narrative you have to

- avoid `select` and use direct `range` reference

  and consequently prevent merged cells to enlarge the cells range affected by the code
- swap the OptionButtons codes

as follows:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    'Option Button Hide
    With Columns("F:F").Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
   'Option Button Unhide
    With Columns("F:F").Font
        .Color = -10477568
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```